# Шаблонные класcы C++. C3203

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Добрый день, возникла следующая проблема касающаяся шаблонных классов в C++.

Структура проекта следующая:

Имеет значение что есть три *.h файла, они располагаются ниже. В первом классе имеется структура Triplet и класс в котором интересен метод `void CalculateLocalPositions()`.

```
// ----------------------
// second_task_manager.h 
// ----------------------

struct Triplet
{
    std::string dotName;
    std::string dotKeyPoints;
    int interpolationOrder;

    Triplet() : 
         dotName(""), dotKeyPoints(""), interpolationOrder(0) {}
    Triplet(std::string dotName, std::string dotKeyPoints, int order) :
         dotName(dotName), dotKeyPoints(dotKeyPoints), interpolationOrder(order) {}

};

template<typename T>
class SecondTaskManager
{
    public:
    SecondTaskManager(const double T, std::string dotsFileName, std::string conditionsFileName);
    ...
    LocalSolver<T>* localSoverPtr_;
    void CalculateLocalPositions(); // ЭТОТ МЕТОД!!!

    private:
    std::vector<Triplet> triplets_;
};

#include"second_task_manager_impl.h"
```

Реализация отмеченного метода показана ниже, и хранится в другом *.h файле (предыдущая строка кода подключает его). Из реализации видно что интересный мне метод вызывает метод класса `LocalSolver` через указатель.

```
// --------------------------
// second_task_manager_impl.h 
// --------------------------

template<typename T>
inline void SecondTaskManager<T>::CalculateLocalPositions()
{
    std::vector<DotPosPair<T>> lol;

    localSoverPtr_->CalculateDotsLocalPos(triplets_);//(triplets_, &lol);
}
```

В самом классе LocalSolver данный метод реализован следующим образом (В качестве аргумента передается вектор из триплетов `std::vector<Triplet> & triplets`).

```
// ----------------------
// local_pos_solver.h 
// ----------------------

#include"../SecTaskManager/second_task_manager.h"


template<typename T>
class LocalSolver
{
public:
    LocalSolver();
    ~LocalSolver();

    void CalculateDotsLocalPos(std::vector<Triplet> & triplets) 
        { std::cout << "lol\n" }

private:
    InterpolationSolver<T>* solverPtr_;
    double T_;
};
```

И при компиляции возникает ряд ошибок, и я никак не пойму из-за чего.

Текст ошибок:

> [image: Ошибка]
>
> - Ошибка C3203 *"allocator": неспециализированный класс шаблон нельзя использовать в качестве аргумента шаблон для параметра шаблон "_Alloc", требуется действительный тип*
> - Ошибка C2923 *std::vector: "Triplet" не является допустимым аргументом типа шаблон для параметра "_Ty"*
> - Ошибка C2065 *Triplet: необъявленный идентификатор*

Сам main.cpp:

```
#include"SecondTask\SecTaskManager\second_task_manager.h"

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    try
    {
        SecondTaskManager<float> manager(1.4, "SecondTaskFiles/dots", "/SecondTaskFiles/conditions");
        manager.CalculateLocalPositions(); // ВОТ МЕСТО ВЫЗОВА
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: При компиляции ЧЕГО возникает ошибка? Мы же не видим, может, вы в .cpp забыли включить .h-файлы :) И, пожалуйста, не надо вот этих вот картинок - что, трудно перенести сообщения в текст?...

Comment: @Harry при компиляции проекта под VS 2015. Добавил main.cpp и добавил все #include которые по идее нужны для корректной работы, ну кроме vector, и.т.д. По поводу картинки, хорошо, если Вам так удобнее - перенесу

Comment: Ощущение, что `CalculateDotsLocalPos(triplets_)` не видит, что такое `triplets_`. Посмотрите, чтоб у вас точно определение `Triplet` включено было. В крайнем случае - пропустите через препроцессор и посмотрите, где впервые встречается `Triple`.

Comment: @Harry, `triplets_` это private член класса SecondTaskManager. Я его добавил сюда в код. Ну в фрагментах кода выше, в хэдере `local_pos_solver.h` подключен `second_task_manager.h` в котором содержится `Triplet`, и по `F12` переходит на нужную структуру. Попробовал передавать просто `Triplet` вместо `std::vector<Triplet>` и пишет: _Ошибка C2061 синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "Triplet"_ .

Answer (score 1):

Тот факт, что определение шаблона `class SecondTaskManager` в заголовочном файле `second_task_manager.h` содержит в себе

```
LocalSolver<T>* localSoverPtr_;
```

намекает на то, что `local_pos_solver.h` у вас включается в `second_task_manager.h` (хоть это и не видно явно из того кода, который вы привели).

При этом `local_pos_solver.h` также явно включает в себя `second_task_manager.h`.

Если это так, то налицо зацикленное включение заголовочных файлов, которое сразу и объясняет происходящее.

Answer (score 0):

Так и не разобрался в чем была ошибка, (возможно зацикливание при подключении *.h файлов или еще что-то). Разрешил проблему использованием `std::tuple`.